# add new column in APYDataGridBundle nor work

Tags: symfony

I try add new column to APYDataGridBundle

here is code :

```
$source->manipulateRow(
            function ($row)
                {
                    /**
                     * @var $row Row
                     */
                    $row->setField('newColumn', $row->getEntity()->getMorbidity());

                    return $row;
                }
            );
```

but it dont show on rendered table, how to show it ?

rest of code :

```
 /**
         * @var Grid $grid
         */
        $grid = $this->get('grid');


        $grid->setSource($source);


        $grid->hideColumns(array('id','date_create','hidden''number'));

        $grid->hideFilters();

        $grid->setActionsColumnTitle(null);

        $grid->getColumn('value')->setTitle('price');




        $userColumns = array('debtor_name','debtor_type','value', 'sell_price', 'date_sell','date_sell2');
        $grid->setColumnsOrder($userColumns);


        $myRowAction = new RowAction('see', 'CompanyController_editCompanyPartner', false, '_self');
        $grid->addRowAction($myRowAction);



        return $grid->getGridRes
```

ponse('meaCoreBundle:Base:grid.html.twig');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are merely adding a field when you need to be adding the whole column. Try:

```
$grid->addColumn(new TextColumn(['id' => 'newColumn', 'title' => 'Your Title']));
```